# Connection timeout error when sending mail from Zohomail using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, zoho, cloud9

Below is my Node app.js code. With these settings, I am receiving a connection timeout error. Any idea what I am missing here?

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: '<myemail@example.com>',
        pass: '<myemailpassword>'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: "<fromemail@example.com>",
  to: "<toemail@example.com>",
  subject: "Hello",
  generateTextFromHTML: true,
  html: { path: './tmpl.html' }
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response);
  }
  transporter.close();
});
```

Error shown

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/mailapp/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:557:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/mailapp/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:530:20)
    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/home/ubuntu/workspace/mailapp/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:248:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some cloud providers disable ports like 465 and 587, try using port 2525 instead of 465.

**Update**

Since you're using Cloud9 for this I found out they have blocked all outbound smtp calls from their servers. If you need to send anyways you need to choose another cloud provider or use one of their recommended services.

https://community.c9.io/t/how-can-i-send-email-from-my-app/1262

Comment: Tried changing the port to 2525, still receiving the same error!

Comment: who's your cloud provider ?

Comment: I am using Cloud9 online IDE for this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I moved to Sublime and executed it from my cmd, and it worked :) Thanks a lot.