# Connection timeout error while using gmail-send in node.js back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, backend, nodemailer

I tried to send email using gmail-send package in the node.js back-end.

```
var send = require('gmail-send')({
    user: '*@gmail.com',
    pass: '*',
    subject: '*',
    to: '*@gmail.com'
})
send({
    html: stringTemplate
}, function(err, res, full){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

This is my code but I got this error.

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:771:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (E:\project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:757:20)
    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (E:\project\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:229:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

I'm struggling with this problem for a long time but I can't find solution.
Before I used nodemailer, but I also get the same error.
Please help me. Thank you for careful watching.

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752772/connection-timeout-error-when-sending-mail-from-zohomail-using-nodemailer this will help you, if not then please let me know

Comment: HI, thank you for your reply. But I think this is not my problem. I'm testing backend by localhost now.

Comment: I recommend you to use nodemailer for sending emails in node.js

Comment: I used nodemailer before but I got same error.